# Angular 5 + Font Awesome: Appending icon into DOM

Tags: angular

I have function in my component, that generates preview of an image that is going to be upload. In preview I have Remove button with Font Awesome icon, that won't get displayed.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { 
    faGlobeAmericas,
    faUsers,
    faUser,
    faLock,
    faImage,
    faTimes
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-feed',
    templateUrl: './feed.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './feed.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})

export class FeedComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('feedImage') imageInput:any;
    faImage = faImage;
    faTimes = faTimes;


    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }

    setPrivacy(privacy){
        [...]
    }

    browseImage(){
        [...]
    }

    insertImage(event){
        [...]
    }

    generatePreview() {
        let file = this.imageInput.nativeElement.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (e:any) => {
            let url = e.target.result;
            this.postPreview = `
            <img class="previewImage" src="${url}" width="auto" height="auto">
                <div class="btn btn-sm remove_rich_media" id="remove_prev">
                remove <fa-icon [icon]="faTimes"></fa-icon>
                </div>
            </img>
            `;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    reset(){
        [...]
    }

    makePost(){
        [...]
    }

}
```

As I am still learning Angular, my understanding is that code I am trying to append is not going through compiler, this why `<fa-icon [icon]="faTimes"></fa-icon>` isn't being converted into format that gets displayed and now somehow I have to turn this small junk of code into component that gets compiled and then use that component as content in my function.

Solution that I don't want to do is the one where you use Font Awesome in `<i class="fa fa-times"></i>` way. As I read, in that solution you would load all the icons and as I use only few icons in my project I see it as "Not so good solution"

Comment: are you getting any error in console?

Comment: @Chellappan No, but I used to get sanitation warning, that basically told my `<fa-icon [icon]="faTimes"></fa-icon>` element was removed for security reasons. So for that I created pipe that fixed that and now it appends `<fa-icon [icon]="faTimes"></fa-icon>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following guide on how to properly install font-awesome:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-include-font-awesome

People usually tend to forget to add a reference to font-awesome.css

Just a warning though, this link describes the process for the latest version of angular, since you are using angular 5, angular.json might be named differently. Just search all .json files at the root of the application that have a similar structure and apply the changes there.

dont forget: you would need to stop serving and run ng serve again.

Answer (score 0):

You could do is this:

HTML:

```
<div #previewImage [innerHtml]="postPreview" style="display: none"></div>
```

TS:

```
@ViewChild('previewImage') previewImage: ElementRef;
postPreview = '';

generatePreview() {
    let file = this.imageInput.nativeElement.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (e:any) => {
        let url = e.target.result;
        this.postPreview = `
        <img class="previewImage" src="${url}" width="auto" height="auto">
            <div class="btn btn-sm remove_rich_media" id="remove_prev">
            remove <fa-icon [icon]="faTimes"></fa-icon>
            </div>
        </img>
        `;

        //Might need this: changeDetectionRef.detectChanges();

        console.log(this.previewImage.nativeElement); //This should be your interpreted HTML code
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using what is written in here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome, I ended up doing this...
...Basically you import them, like I had done, but you add them into library or something...

```
//this is what I already had
import { 
    faGlobeAmericas,
    faUsers,
    faUser,
    faLock,
    faImage,
    faTimes
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

//This is what I needed to add
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';

library.add(faGlobeAmericas);
library.add(faUsers);
library.add(faLock);

//and so on...
```

And now when you need to use any of those icons you can just write:`<fa-icon icon="globe-americas"></fa-icon>` where ever you need to display that icon.

And when you use brand icons, you need need to import those icons from `@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons`